# Обращение к ключу массива через квадратные скобки

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите разобраться почему такой код выдает true

```
[0,2,5][2,1] == 2
```

Я понял что при обращению к элементу массива он учитывает только последнюю цифру , все что до запятой он не учитывает. Но почему так можно писать и для чего вообще могут быть нужны такие записи?

Comment: Да вы правы, будет учитываться только последнее значение. Зачем? Потому что можно:D На самом деле код очень не читаем и не советуется к написанию. Возможно, автоматическая генерация так делает для уменьшение размера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае используется оператор [запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Согласно документации MDN, выполняет каждый операнд слева направо и возвращает значение последнего операнда.

Зачем использовать? Имхо, в принципе от него нет особенной какой-то пользы за исключением случаев, когда хочется выделиться элегантностью записи многих операций в одну строку (что, как следствие приводит к ухудшению читаемости кода), хотя в принципе это дело вкуса.

Куча примеров есть на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/116827/).

Comment: Кстати, хорошие примеры, кроме присваивания. `while(n = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000), !isPrime(n));` отлично заменяется на `while(!isPrime(n = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000)));`

Comment: @Qwertiy, было непонятно, а стало еще непонятнее :)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F):

```js
var x = (1, 2)
console.log(x)

console.log((3, 4))

console.log(1, (2, 3), 4)

console.log([0, 1, 2, 3][(1,2)])
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3][ 1,2 ])

if (false, true) console.log(10), console.log(20); else ;
```